# Integrating a Thrift ruby server and a Ruby on Rails web app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, thrift

In my free time, I'm currently working on a web app written with Rails, and planning on writing "thick" clients for the desktop and various mobile platforms (who doesn't ?).

I like the concept of Thrift for its multi-language support, and the concept of having one IDL file generating appropriate code for clients (DRY !)

I was wondering what would be the best way / architecture to integrate the Thrift server and Rails.

The only options that come to mind seems sup-optimal :

- call the wepapp APIs from the Thrift server to return data to the thick clients
- plug the thrift server to the DB of the Rails app and do its thing.

For obvious reasons, this seems overkill, redundant and not flexible.

Any suggestion ?

thanks !

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if its overkill :) But I suggest if you want to explore this topic even more that you also look into [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10530638/how-do-i-run-a-ruby-thrift-server-in-production).