# How do I run a Ruby Thrift server in production?

Tags: thrift

I need to implement a Thrift API using Ruby.

- What are my options for running a server in production?
- What is the best option?

Currently I'm just instantiating a SimpleServer and calling #serve on it. This is obviously a crappy solution because if anything goes wrong I need to restart the server (so I'm monitoring it with a script). Also, I assume it is single threaded.

I realize that this is a very basic question, and I am surprised that I haven't been able to find an answer for it by googling.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same question, and haven't been able to find an answer. But you might find the [BaseServer](http://rubydoc.info/gems/thrift/0.9.0/frames) page on rubydoc.info helpful.

I am guessing that `ThreadPoolServer`, `ThreadedServer`, or `MongrelHTTPServer` might be better choices for a production RPC server. This answer will be updated as I investigate further.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, Jim. To be honest, I'd forgotten all about this issue :)


The way I ended up implementing this was by inserting a Rack middleware into the Rails app. I *think* this is it, now packaged as a Gem: 
https://github.com/deees/thrift-rack-middleware

If this suits your needs, try it out. Ping me if you're unable to make it work and I'll see what I did differently.